# Counting elements of multidimensional list according to patterns

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the tuples :

```
a = Range[0, 2];
l2 = Tuples[{a, a}]
```

which gives

```
{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 
2}}
```

I want to find all tuples which contain number 1 exactly once. 
  A possible solution would be :

```
l21 = Cases[l2, {1, x_ /; x != 1} | {x_ /; x != 1, 1}]
```

For the three - dimensional case it would be something like this :

```
l3 = Tuples[{a, a, a}];
Cases[l3, {1, x_ /; x != 1, y_ /; y != 1} | {x_ /; x != 1, 1, 
   y_ /; y != 1} | {x_ /; x != 1, y_ /; y != 1, 1}]
```

What would be a shorter way to use patterns in Cases for higher
dimensions, e.g.

```
Tuples[{a,a,a,a,a}]
```

Comment: `l2 = Tuples[a, 2]` and `l3 = Tuples[a, 3]` are a bit simpler and more easily extended to higher dimensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Select[l2, Count[#, 1] == 1 &]
Pick[l2, Counts[#][1] & /@ l2, 1]
Pick[l2, Total@Transpose[1-Unitize[l2-1]], 1]
Cases[{Except[1] ..., 1, Except[1] ...}]@l2
```

> {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}}

```
Select[l3, Count[#, 1] == 1 &]
Pick[l3, Counts[#][1] & /@ l3, 1]
Pick[l3, Total@Transpose[1-Unitize[l3-1]], 1]
Cases[{Except[1] ..., 1, Except[1] ...}]@l3
```

> {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 
>     2}, {1,
>        2, 0}, {1, 2, 2}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}

Comment: Thanks! So easy!

Comment: @user57467, you are welcome.